# Best DB type for a daily no join sorted query of tons of records?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nosql

Once a day I need to:

1. Fetch millions (or more) of sorted by name (not a unique value) s3 blobs.
2. For each blob name there is an expiration rule which I should find (by the blob name) and execute (the rules may change every day)
3. Delete the blobs according the rules I found - some of the early blobs per name (number changes by the rule)

Is there a good DB for storing the data about the blobs (not the data stored in the blobs) so I could find the fastest way possible which blob to delete, or should I just retrieve the blob data from the S3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have "millions" of objects stored in Amazon S3, I would recommend obtaining a list of objects by using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a **daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects**.

You could then write a program to parse this file, perform your logic and delete unwanted objects.

This way, you do not actually need a database -- just use the daily S3 Inventory listing that is provided.

The alternative is to **maintain your own database of objects** by triggering an AWS Lambda function whenever an object is created or deleted. This involves a lot more work, but would be worthwhile if you need an up-to-date listing of objects more often than once per day.